# Chat stuck at automated process user

Tags: omnichannel, automated-process

One of the user in my team, He started a chat but there was no case created for the chat.  I think it is due to chat stuck at automated process user.

I am looking how to find which chats are stuck with automated process user and any work around for this ?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you able to see the chat in omni-channel console? What happens when the user picks up the chat?

Comment: They are able to pick the chat as well as chatting with the client.

Comment: Does the agent have proper access to the fields and objects mentioned in pre-chat form. Please verify that.

Comment: This particular user have chat pre-form(as well as system accesses) access similar to other users